# How to subset a data set based on a specific condition?

Tags: r, subset

I am working with a data set that has over 500 000 observations. It is available here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00352/. My goal is to remove some of the rows based on the following buzzwords:

```
buzzwords = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
```

If the column Description contains these buzzwords, for example, "Apple" contains "A", I should remove the entire row. I wrote this function:

```
isUndesirable2 = function(x){  
  c=FALSE

  for (i in 1:length(buzzwords)){  
    if (str_detect(toupper(x),buzzwords[i])){
      c=TRUE
    }   
    break  
  }  
  return(c)
}
```

The function above works well, I tried it on multiple examples. However, when I try to subset the original data set:

```
dataset43 = dataset2[which(!isUndesirable2(as.character(dataset2$Description))),]
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning message:
In if (str_detect(toupper(x), buzzwords[i])) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and the new dataset43 is empty. Weird!

If anyone more experienced with R can help - I'd really appreciate it. Thanks! PS Sorry about the formatting, it is my first post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind editing your question to include a sample of `dataset2`. The `dput()` function in R is a great way to share data sets and makes the error reproducible (and probably fixable).

Answer (score 0):

Consider a more R-like approach

```
buzzwords = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
dataset2 <- data.frame(Description=c("Apple", "Bee", "Zoo", "Green", "Hospital", "Yoohoo", "You"))

library(stringr)
```

I use `outer` for all-to-all comparison of `dataset2$Description` and `buzzwords` in `str_detect(i, j)`. Then `filter` dataset2 based on whether any buzzword was found or not

```
is_buzzword_present <- outer(dataset2$Description, buzzwords, function(i, j) str_detect(toupper(i), j))
dplyr::filter(dataset2, !apply(is_buzzword_present, 1, any))

#   Description
# 1         Zoo
# 2         You
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I got this error:Error in filter(dataset2, !apply(is_buzzword_present, 1, any)) : 
  'filter' is longer than time series
In addition: Warning message:
In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: I should have specified where `filter` was coming from. But I'm not sure if that's the only issue

Answer (score 0):

Using the example above we can do:

```
subset(dataset2,!grepl(paste(buzzwords,collapse="|"),do.call(paste,dataset2)))
  Description
3         Zoo
6      Yoohoo
7         You
```

Comment: Thanks!! Do you maybe know which version of R does grepl require? I have R 3.4.2.

Comment: Greco is in all versions